# Has the service stopped or is it waiting ?

Tags: services

When I do `service <service name> stop`, I get an immediate response:

`<service name> stop/waiting`.

Does this mean the service has stopped already?

Or does it mean the process of stopping the service has started ?

Answer (score 2):

`<service-name> stop/waiting` means that `<service-name>` has been `stop`ped and is now in the state of `waiting`. Analogous to that, a message like `<service-name> start/running` tells you that the `<service-name>` has been `start`ed and is now in the state of `running`.